# jsp conditional based include file is not working as expected

Tags: java, php, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I have a jsp called view.jsp which has to work in two different scenarios.

1. It has to work independently(I use ajax requests to execute this jsp).
2. It will included by another jsp called main.jsp.

Whenever a request come to server i have a common code in validate.jsp which will be used by almost all the jsp's. I'm including the validate.jsp into view.jsp.

Ex: view.jsp

`<%@ include file="validate.jsp" %>`

```
`// code specific to view.jsp`
```

This time it works fine if i'm sending request to view.jsp.

But the problem is when i include view.jsp in main.jsp i'm getting some errors. Because of redundant data.

EX: `main.jsp`

`<%@ include file="validate.jsp"%>`

`// some code specific to main.jsp`

`<%@ include file="view.jsp"%>`

to make view.jsp to be work in both cases

i's written a condition like below

Ex: `view.jsp`

`<% if(request.getParameter("tra")!=null){ %>`

```
`<%@ include file="validate.jsp" %>`
```

`<% }   %>`

`// code specifit to view.jsp`

i'm sure that this condition will be false when i'm executing main.jsp. But this condition based file include is not at all working when i execute main.jsp i'm getting errors like below.

An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /validte.jsp
Duplicate field main_jsp.dt
`6: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
7:     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

`An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /validte.jsp
Duplicate field main_jsp.bookInfo
7:     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /validte.jsp
Duplicate field main_jsp.token

But the same style coding is working as expected in php. Please some one guide me to make it work out.

Comment: it seems dat u r declaring variables in main.jsp and validate.jsp with the same name. try removing the declaration of variable "dt" n "bookInfo" in validate.jsp

Comment: I think you need to use <jsp:include> instead of include directive.

Comment: @Arvind : I'm declaring "dt" and "bookinfo" in validate.jsp. This validate.jsp is included by main.jsp and as well as view.jsp. when i include view.jsp into main.jsp validate.jsp is again including into main.jsp. This causing problem. So added a condition to not include the validate.jsp into view.jsp when it is including by the main.jsp. Unfortunately that condition based include is not working.

Comment: @pikrut I can't use the <jsp: inlcude> because i have code to be used by the both main.jsp and view.jsp of the validate.jsp but not the output of validate.jsp